# Refresh a single Div and nothing else

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using an rss feed reader into a webpage.

```
<div id="divRss" class="content-1"></div>


$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#divRss').FeedEk({
            FeedUrl: 'https://it.finance.yahoo.com/notizie/fonte-reuters/?format=rss',
            MaxCount: 10,
            DateFormat: 'LLL',
            DateFormatLang: 'it',
            ShowDesc: false,
            TitleLinkTarget:'_blank',
            ShowPubDate:true
        });

    });
```

I want to refresh this single #divRss div, at least every 30 minutes.
Maybe the setInterval function() can help me, but i don't know how to use it into my example.
If someone can explain how can i do that, i'd be really gratetful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds). The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

> *setInterval(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...)*

```js
function feed() {
  $('#divRss').FeedEk({
    FeedUrl: 'https://it.finance.yahoo.com/notizie/fonte-reuters/?format=rss',
    MaxCount: 10,
    DateFormat: 'LLL',
    DateFormatLang: 'it',
    ShowDesc: false,
    TitleLinkTarget: '_blank',
    ShowPubDate: true
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  feed();
  setInterval(feed, 30 * 60 * 1000);

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! really helpful